# Downloading Image from Api and populate Image in CollectionViewController using Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I am able to find the response data in array but not able to download and populate in Collection View. I have tried to upload the image from the image container from application but not able to download and upload by API

**Code**

```
    func get_data_from_url(){


    //API calls
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://android.eposapi.co.uk/?app_id=A1A2A3A4&app_key=K1K2K3K4&request=gallery")



    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "gallery"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
        data,response,error in

        if error != nil{
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        //Print out response object
        print("response= \(response)")
        //print response body
       // let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

       // print("response data = \(responseString!)")

        var json: NSArray!
        do {
            json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as? NSArray
            print(json)
            print(json[0])

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.collectionView!.reloadData()
        }


    }
    task.resume()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    get_data_from_url()


    self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


}



    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell
let image = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

    image.image = images[indexPath.row]



return cell
}
```

Tell me any one solution how to download images of anytype (either png or jpg) and populate in the `UICollectionView` using `mutable urlRequest`/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try another way like NSURLSession to download the data

```
   var url: NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://android.eposapi.co.uk/?app_id=A1A2A3A4&app_key=K1K2K3K4&request=gallery")! 

   var downloadPhotoTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask =   
  NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(location: NSURL, response: NSURLResponse, error: NSError) -> Void in

    var downloadedImage: UIImage = UIImage.imageWithData(NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(location))
})  
downloadPhotoTask.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done exactly this recently, it is a Memory game that fetches images from instagram and displays the images in a UICollectionView. Please checkout the [SwiftIntro project on Github](https://github.com/Sajjon/SwiftIntro)

I fetch images using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire):

```
func prefetchImages(urls: [URLRequestConvertible], done: Closure) {

    imageDownloader.downloadImages(URLRequests: urls) {
        response in
        done()
    }
}
```

This is a "prefetch" solution, then I can retrieve the images using this function:

```
func imageFromCache(url: NSURL) -> UIImage? {
    guard let cache = imageCache else { return nil }
    let imageFromCache = cache.imageForRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url), withAdditionalIdentifier: nil)
    return imageFromCache
}
```

Checkout the [ImagePrefetcher class](https://github.com/Sajjon/SwiftIntro/blob/master/SwiftIntro/HTTP/ImagePrefetcher.swift).

The [MemoryDataSourceClass](https://github.com/Sajjon/SwiftIntro/blob/master/SwiftIntro/DataSourceAndDelegates/MemoryDataSourceAndDelegate.swift) which implements the UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate protocols returns UICollectionViewCells of type [CardCVCell](https://github.com/Sajjon/SwiftIntro/blob/master/SwiftIntro/Views/Cells/CollectionViewCells/CardCVCell/CardCVCell.swift) which contains an UIImageView created in its .Xib. I set the image on the UIImageView in this method:

```
func updateWithModel(model: Model) {
    guard let card = model as? CardModel else { return }
    guard let cachedImage = ImagePrefetcher.sharedInstance.imageFromCache(card.imageUrl) else { return }
    cardFrontImageView.image = cachedImage
    flipped = card.flipped
}
```

Sorry about the ImagePrefetcher.sharedInstance Singleton ;), Singletons are bad (as discussed [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/singletons/) and [here](http://www.kyleclegg.com/blog/9272013why-singletons-are-bad))! I have not yet set up Dependency Injection using amazing [Swinject](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject), but will do so soon! :)

Comment: your Answer sounds too complex. I am asking to implement in the existing one that i sent not creating a new one

Comment: "Tell me any one solution how to download images of anytype", I gave you a proposol of a good solution using Alamofire, why do you want to invent the wheel again?

Comment: I think you should use NSURLSessionDownloadTask instead of DataTask, please see https://www.raywenderlich.com/67081/cookbook-using-nsurlsession

Comment: (
    "http://demo.orderjoint.co.uk/img/14635798701216.png",
    "http://demo.orderjoint.co.uk/img/14635797079652.png",
    "http://demo.orderjoint.co.uk/img/14634976191460.png",
    "http://demo.orderjoint.co.uk/img/14635797438898.png",
    "http://demo.orderjoint.co.uk/img/14635797869611.png",
    "http://demo.orderjoint.co.uk/img/14635563575240.jpg"
)
This data i can able to retrieve. but the above method you sent is not working.